# R - merge lists into one without putting each list's number

Tags: r, list

I have bunch of lists like this:

```
out[3]

[[3]]

[1] "forum=28&mid=11883" 
[2] "forum=29&mid=11884" 

out[4]

[[4]]

[1] "forum=30&mid=11885" 
[2] "forum=31&mid=11886"
```

the outcome that I want is

```
[1] "forum=28&mid=11883"

[2] "forum=29&mid=11884" 

[3] "forum=30&mid=11885" 

[4] "forum=31&mid=11886"
```

without [3], [4] (the order of each list) into the output list. Most of the "combine list" method out there (i.e. c(list1,list2), combine, paste, rbind..) made me include the order of each list like below

Any suggestions? will be much appreciated. ( I was thinking about convert lists to dataframe and use rbind, but I have 50,000 lists (longer than this) and i expect it will slow down the process so I didn't go to that path..)

Comment: Is `unlist` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `unlist()`.  Here is an example:

```
out <- list(
  c("a", "b"),
  c("c", "d")
)

out[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"
```

Now use `unlist()`

```
unlist(out)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Comment: That was going to be my answer, too. The questioner may also need to be advised that the '[1]' and so on are not part of the object but rather part of the behavior of of the implicit `print(eval(.))` during interactive sessions. To get the output without the element numbers they may want to use `cat`.